# Sorting array using template

Tags: php, arrays

I have a multidimensional array used as a template, and then, another multiarray with mixed values. I have tried to sort the mixed array to look like the template array, but still no success for now

The template array:

```
$routes = [['A','B','C','D'],['A','C','E','F'],['D','O','A','F']]
$points = [['C','A','A','B','C','C'], ['E','E','C','A'],['F','O','O','A','A']]
```

The routes array is the template array.
I have tried something like this:

```
for ($i=0;$i<=$idx;$i++) {
    $points1 = usort($points[$i], function($a, $b) use ($routes) {
        return array_search($a, $routes[$i]) - array_search($b, $routes[$i]);
    });        
}
```

where `$idx` represents the array lenght.
Could someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `array_keys` instead of `array_search` and send the key of the current $point you are treating to your callback :

```
$routes = [['A','B','C','D'],['A','C','E','F'],['D','O','A','F']];
$points = [['C','A','A','B','C','C'], ['E','E','C','A'],['F','O','O','A','A']];

foreach ($points as $key => &$point) {
  usort ($point, function ($a, $b) use ($key, $routes) {
    return array_keys($routes[$key], $a) > array_keys($routes[$key], $b);
  });
}

print_r($points);
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => A
            [2] => B
            [3] => C
            [4] => C
            [5] => C
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => C
            [2] => E
            [3] => E
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => O
            [1] => O
            [2] => A
            [3] => A
            [4] => F
        )

)
```

You were not that far though. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the code is not yet ok.. It does not order the results as wanted..

Comment: @rosuandreimihai Uh, then you may have to add some details on the output you expect. Don't you want to orders points with the corresponding route ?

Comment: Yes, but the result given to me looks different then yours: [['C','A','A','B','C','C'], ['E','E','C','A'],['F','O','O','A','A']]

Comment: @rosuandreimihai Did you copy the exact same code as me ? Including the reference (`&`) on the `$point` variable ? Otherwise it's not sorting anything. That's why you would have an unchanged result.

Comment: @rosuandreimihai The result is the same on phptester, check PHP 5.4 instead of the default PHP 5.3 value.

Comment: So, if I have PHP 5.3 this code will not help me.., any ideea on how to convert it to php 5.3?

Comment: @rosuandreimihai Of course, use array() instead of [] to init your arrays: `array(array('A','B','C','D'),array('A','C','E','F'),array('D','O','A','F'));`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73373/discussion-between-rosuandreimihai-and-clement-malet).